# Run xampp on external hard drive on XP and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, xampp, external, hard-drive

I've installed XAMPP on an external hard drive. My Windows XP desktop can run XAMPP fine from the external. But when I plug the external into my Windows 7 laptop, XAMPP doesn't run. I run the control panel. It says `Install(er) Directory: No Installer Package Found`. When I click Start next to Apache and MySql it says `Apache / MySql started` but the Running green message does not appear, or appears for a split second then disappears. Localhost is unavailable.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
HR

Answer (score 1):

Go to control `panel>administration tools` and select IIS Management Services. Once opened right click on the root of IIS (your PC's name) and select stop.